# Automating LibreOffice Calc from outside via COM

Tags: lotusscript, libreoffice-calc

I tried accessing a Sheet in an ODS doc. Everything works fine - I can access Named ranges and so on - but if I try to access a simple cell via its Row/Col indices I get an error...

Code is Lotus Notes basic  (because of the Variants...)

```
Dim rowFieldNameIndex As Integer
Dim rowStartMergeIndex As Long
Dim I As Integer  
Dim oCell As Variant    ' Cell object.
Dim oSheet As Variant
Dim FieldName As String

    rowFieldNameIndex = Val( GetOODocProperty (pOOObj, "FieldNameRow"))
    rowStartMergeIndex = Val( GetOODocProperty (pOOObj, "MergeStartRow"))
    '--> both working

    If Not pOOobj Is Nothing Then
        Set oSheet = pOOobj.Sheets(0)

        MsgBox pOOobj.Sheets.Count           'works
        MsgBox oSheet.CellsEnumeration.Count
        'getCellByPosition(col,row)
        Set oCell = oSheet.getCellByPosition(1, 1)  'ERROR?!?!?  getCellByPosition is no tan Instance Member??? so how can I access a Cell

        OCell.String = "Test"
    End If  

Public Function GetOODocProperty (pOODoc As Variant, ByVal strVarName) As String
    Dim userProps As Variant

    On Error Resume Next
    'get UserDefined Properties
    Set userProps = pOODoc.DocumentProperties.getUserDefinedProperties()

    'Try to Remove; on Error Property doesen't exists yet
    If userProps.getPropertySetInfo().hasPropertyByName(strVarName) = True Then
           'http://api.openoffice.org/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/beans/XPropertySet.html
         GetOODocProperty = userProps.getPropertyValue(strVarName)
    Else
        GetOODocProperty = ""
    End If
End function
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem was:

`pOOBJ.Sheets(0)` does not return a sheet Object in COM!!!!

this will work:

`pOOObj.GetSheets().getbyIndex(0)`

Comment: The `Sheets(0)` syntax seems language-specific.  I think `getSheets().getByIndex()` or `getSheets().getByName()` are more reliable for most languages.  Usually what I do is look how it is done in Java and then apply that as closely as possible to whatever UNO-enabled language I am working in.